# IsEnabled binding to a boolean

Tags: wpf, button, data-binding, isenabled

I have a list a simple dialog box which contains a few checkboxes, I wanted to have an Ok button that would be disabled unless the user changed a setting. In my view I have an OkEnabled property that I was binding the isEnabled property of the button to, if a check box changes its value it sets OkEnabled to true, but for some reason this doesnt enable the button.

```
public bool OkEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return m_okEnabled;
    }
    set
    {
        m_okEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("OkEnabled");
    }
}
```

```
<Button Content="OK" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Height="23" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20" Name="m_okbutton" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
        Click="okClick" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=OkEnabled}"/>
```

For some reason the Ok button won't change state when the OkEnabled property changes state. If I bind the IsEnabled property to one of the checkboxes I can see the button change state as the check box changes.

Comment: Do you see any binding errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my view I have an OkEnabled property

By default, bindings are relative to the DataContext, not the view. Did you set the view as its own DataContext ?

Comment: I have set the DataContext of the dialog to be the view which contains the OkEnabled property. Is that what you meant, sorry I am quite new to WPF.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Check the output window in Visual Studio to see if there are binding errors

Comment: no unfortunately there aren't any binding errors. I don't understand why the button does change state if I bind it to one of the CheckBox property's.

Comment: whoops my view didn't inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged. Thanks for your help sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: "Thanks for your help sorry for wasting your time!" What do you mean by that? When I emigrated to this country to study, the first thing that professors taught us was: "The ONLY stupid question is the one you don't ask". The DoJ et. al. judge told Bill Gates: "Failures teach more that successes - You have never failed, Mr. Gates".

Answer (score 1):

As you said that OkEnabled property is in view. which is not correct if you are using MVVM. It should be in model and assign model object into datacontext of view.