# Binding of Button isEnabled Property to a Boolean Does Not Change When INotifyPropertyChanged Fires

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I have been attempting to successfully bind a Button's isEnabled property to a Boolean variable. After updating the Boolean, the Button's enabled state does not change. I used the helpful documentation from Microsoft for this subject to form my code, found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface/). Upon searching StackOverflow, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770947/isenabled-binding-to-a-boolean) article a regarding similar problem. It did not assist me in fixing this bug.

```
public class BackState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool _isEnabled;
    public bool isEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnabled;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _isEnabled)
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("isEnabled");
                Debug.WriteLine("NotifyPropertyChanged was called successfully");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

}
```

Snippet of XAML code:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding BackObject}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:FieldModifier="public" IsEnabled="{Binding isEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="Back_Click" x:Name="Back" Foreground="DarkGray" Content="&#xE76B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="#33FFFFFF" FontSize="20" Margin="40,70,0,133" />
</Grid>
```

My Boolean Change Function

```
public static void ChangeState(bool b)
{
    BackState bs = new BackState();
    if(b == true)
    {
        bs.isEnabled = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Enabled Property");
    }else{
        bs.isEnabled = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("Disabled Property");
    }
}
```

And here is the BackObject definition

```
<local:BackState x:Key="BackObject"/>
```

In the GUI, the button constantly remains enabled. (Regardless of if ChangeState function is called) It should change disable/enable according to the called function.

Comment: Take a look at the output window. Do you have an error regarding a binding expression?

Comment: @dktaylor Nope, it seems to be error-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ChangeState` method you are creating a new BackState object, whereas this should be a property on the `BackObject` that you are setting as the `DataContext`. Instantiate a `BackState` that is a property on the `BackObject`, and bind to the `isEnabled` property of that object so that the xaml is told to listen for changes to that property.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding BackObject}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:FieldModifier="public" IsEnabled="{Binding yourPropertyWhcihIsBackState.isEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="Back_Click" x:Name="Back" Foreground="DarkGray" Content="&#xE76B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Background="#33FFFFFF" FontSize="20" Margin="40,70,0,133" />
</Grid>
```

and then in the method:

```
public static void ChangeState(bool b)
{
    if(b == true)
    {
        yourPropertyWhcihIsBackState.isEnabled = true;
            Debug.WriteLine("Enabled Property");
    }else{
        yourPropertyWhcihIsBackState.isEnabled = false;
        Debug.WriteLine("Disabled Property");
    }
}
```

But this won't work if you are ultimately making changes on an instance of an object to which the xaml is not bound. You seem to be creating a new instance of `BackObject`in your xaml, but it doesn't look like you have any way of accessing this object in your code. Consider setting up a `ViewModel` for accomplishing this. Take a look at [mvvm light](http://www.mvvmlight.net), it's a great mvvm (Model View ViewModel) framework.

Comment: Just to confirm, you wanted me to create a property that returns a newly-created BackState object? Then, do you want me to bind to ThatSameProperty.IsEnabled? I tried this and it still fails to change the enabling. Please forgive me, as I'm new to c#.

Comment: The property should return an existing object that you instantiate I the constructor of the BackObject. The important thing is that you are binding in xaml to the same instance of the object in which the property is changing

Comment: Perhaps add some of your BackObject to your answer so I can give you a better sense of how to implement it. You should also try to add some label bound to your BackObject so that you can be sure the data context is being set up properly

Comment: I added it just in case we had differing perspectives on what it is.

Comment: Where is the ChangeState method? Are you using MVVM?

Comment: The ChangeState function is in another class.

Comment: So the class which contains ChangeState should have an instance of BackState as a property for the view to bind to.

Comment: I implemented this right now and upon building the app, I am now getting the error described here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/256997/error-cs1061-ver-1803-compilation-of-xbind-to-stat.html . Which I think is a bug in the VS compiler.